# difference between cp rm and mv in file transfers

Tags: shell-script, file-transfer

I could write `mv` as

```
mv()
{
   cp $1 $2
   rm $1
}
```

Therefore, in file transfers `cp rm` and `mv` could be equal, but there are dissimilarities.

How are the two options different?

Comment: `mv` only behaves that way when you are moving a file to a different filesystem.

Comment: Using `cp` creates a new file - new inode, blocks reserved on disk for the physical file, copying the blocks of the old file to the new file, making a inode/name-pair in a directory.  If you're using `mv` on the other hand - *as long as it's within the same filesystem* - all that is done is making an inode/name-pair in a directory and removing the old inode/name-pair.  No new inode, no new blocks, no copying of data; because you continue to use the old inode and physical file.  If it's moved to *another filesystem* though, a new inode will be created, blocks reserved and blocks moved..